# Accent insensitive search with SQLite for html5sql

Tags: sqlite, mobile, cordova, web-sql

I'm a little bit confused with a quite simple looking problem.

I'm working on an offline HTLM5 web sql database for mobile, using [html5sql.js](http://html5sql.com/).

So far, everything works fine, except the search with accents.

Here is an example:

```
Records: "Céline", "Elisa"
Search "el" --> "Elisa"
Search "él" --> No result
```

I would expect to find both results in both searches.

So far, I don't have any encoding specs in my queries. I read several posts about collation, but I did not manage to use any of them.
Would you have a typical example of how to write a query for this search?

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap does not have any portable way to do case-insensitive comparisons of non-ASCII characters.

You could remove accents from your strings and store those separately.

Answer (score 0):

You could try my open source library, [ydn-db](https://bitbucket.org/ytkyaw/ydn-db/wiki/Home), which has full text search. A demo app can be found [here](http://dev.yathit.com/demo/ydn-db-text/pubmed-search/index.html). Currently, it only has English language normalization though. You can find more languages on [NaturalNode repo](https://github.com/NaturalNode/natural) and recompiled it.